# How to get a list of running applications with VBS without using a call to word?

Tags: vbscript, ms-word

We are using the script below to kill any open windows that may interfere with the  kiosk operation.

it uses word to return a list of running application not processes.

Problem is the script I have calls on Word and word keeps crashing.  Seems like there should be a way to do this without the call to word.

here's the code I am using

```
sub closeWindows()
Set Word = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set Tasks = Word.Tasks
For Each Task in Tasks
If Task.Visible AND Task.Name = "Sign Up for Facebook" Then Task.Close()
If Task.Visible AND Task.Name = "Log In | Facebook: Facebook" Then Task.Close()
Next
Word.Quit
end sub
Do
closeWindows
Wscript.Sleep 1000
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two options preferable to the solution you are suggesting:

1. Lock down / harden the kiosk to prevent the use of unwanted applications.
2. If you use a "watchdog" script like this, populate the script with the *known good* applications, not the ones you do not want.

Both of these options are far more sustainable than keep a blacklist.